# Correctly setting the CSS styling for a class of divs

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have a bunch of similar divs, that I want to style as rectangles. For short example, I have:

```
  <div id="foundation1" class="emptySlot"></div>
  <div id="foundation2" class="emptySlot"></div>
  <div id="foundation3" class="emptySlot"></div>
```

I made them all have class `"emptySlot"` so that we can easily set the external styling. I tried the following for the styling without success:

```
emptySlot { 
    #rectangle {
    width:       50px;
    height:      100px;
    background:  blue;
    }
}
```

I pointed my browser to these files, but it appeared to have no effect. I am completely new to web technologies, so please help me get started (or point me somewhere!)

Thanks for all the help!

**EDIT:** An important feature I would like is unique positions of the rectangles on the screen, what is a good solution for this in terms of minimal code? Should this be in the HTML or the CSS? It would be nice for every `div` to have the same styling, and then be able to specify unique positions. It looks like the best place for that would be HTML.

Comment: Are you using any CSS pre-processors? Nesting rules like that wouldn't work with plain CSS. Also CSS class selector needs a `.` in front of the class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
emptySlot { 
    #rectangle {
    width:       50px;
    height:      100px;
    background:  blue;
    }
}
```

This syntax in CSS isn't correct, first a class is represented by adding a dot `.` before its name, such as:

```
.emptySlot {
}
```

Second, you can't have a style inside a style in pure CSS.

There are different ways to assign these "rectangle" styles to your `divs`.

**Method 1**

```
/* First Div */
.emptySlot:nth-child(1) { 
    width:       50px;
    height:      100px;
    background:  blue;
}
/* Second Div */
.emptySlot:nth-child(2) { 
    width:       50px;
    height:      100px;
    background:  blue;
}
```

**Method 2**

```
/* First Div */
#foundation1 { 
    width:       50px;
    height:      100px;
    background:  blue;
}
```

And so on.. There's more methods of course...

Answer (score 2):

You don't even have an element with an id="rectangle" so take it out of your css definition. Just use:

```
.emptySlot
{
width: 50px;
height 100px;
background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no complexity needed. Just use,

```
.emptySlot {
    width: 50px;
    height 100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of my answer above?

Answer (score 1):

Add a '.' to the CSS element so:

```
.emptySlot { 
    #rectangle {
    width:       50px;
    height:      100px;
    background:  blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.` is the class selector

```
.emptySlot { width : 50px; height : 100px; background : blue; }
```

Alternatively, you could have two classes:

```
<div class="empty-slot rectangle"></div>

.empty-slot { /*...*/ }
.rectangle { /*...*/ }
```

`#` is the ID prefix

```
#foundation1 {/*...*/}
```

You can't nest rules inside of one another like that in CSS (regular CSS -- there are tools which allow you to write similar languages and compile down to CSS, and those languages *do* support nesting and other fun features, but that's a totally different ball of wax, and one you don't want to get started on for a long while).